# How to find the file which says, "It works!"

Tags: linux, web-server

If I type "localhost" into a web browser address bar I get a page with the following information:

```
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

I know that this is a file somewhere on my computer. How can I find this file?

Comment: probably better to find out what webserver is running and look in the corresponding directories. If you are desperate though I guess you could do     `grep -r It\ works /*`   but it might take a while

Comment: [`grep`](https://www.google.com/search?q=man+grep)

Comment: Haha. I like how you suggested that brute force method as a last resort.

Comment: There is a chance that "there is no spoon" (the message could be generated dynamically by a printf in the server).

Comment: How do I find out what webserver is running?

Comment: @Wintermute probably not the most pretty way but you could do `netstat -nlp` and look for the line which has port 80 listed as this will be you web server. Look at the program name/PID column. That should give you a clue. If you need more info use the `ps` command to get more information based on the PID

Comment: Maybe /var/www/index.html or /srv/www/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Debian (and its derivatives, like Ubuntu), you can find this file in `/var/www/index.html`.